# Duplicate matching Business & Person accounts

Tags: duplicate-management, person-accounts

Is it possible to implement a functioning duplicate rule across Business & Person accounts?

I created a `Matching_Name__c` field on Account and a matching rule to look for an exact match of this field on both business and person accounts. I then created a duplicate rule using the new matching rule.

Unfortunately, when I create a "Test Account" person and then business account, I do not receive any alert that a duplicate record has been found. Is there any way to do this?

[image: Duplicate rule]

Both records are in the Accounts table and have the same name. The person account was created first, so the duplicate rule should have prevented the business account from being created with the same name.

```
SELECT Matching_Name__c,IsPersonAccount FROM Account WHERE Matching_Name__c!=null ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC
```

| `Matching_Name__c` | `IsPersonAccount` |
| --- | --- |
| Test Account | false |
| Test Account | true |